# Angular 5 include javascript files

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular5

I'm using Angular 5 and I want to include my script files .js

I'm using the script tag in the index.html

When I refresh the page everything works fine, but when i'm using SPA routing my js files does not included

Here's an exemple :

If I refreshed the page

[image]

When i'm using SPA navigation

[image]

Here's **index.html** where i include all my script whith **script** tag

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <base href="/">
    <title>Listeo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/colors/main.css" id="colors">
</head>
<body>
    <app-base></app-base>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/scripts/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/scripts/mmenu.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/scripts/chosen.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/scripts/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/scripts/rangeslider.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/scripts/magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/scripts/waypoints.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/scripts/counterup.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/scripts/tooltips.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/scripts/custom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/scripts/switcher.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here's the navigation bar :

```
<nav id="navigation" class="style-1">
    <ul id="responsive">
        <li>
            <a [routerLink]="['home']" [routerLinkActive]="['current']">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a [routerLink]="['restaurants']" [routerLinkActive]="['current']">Restaurants</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

When I'm using the **href** everything wirks fine, but with **[routerLink]** I'm facing the problem.

Comment: Without being providing the relevant snippets of code it's impossible to tell you what the problem might be. Please rework your post.

Comment: @DiabolicWords done.

Comment: you need to trigger manually the script which  turns the plain slider into the fancy one

Comment: @David is there any sources i can use ? thanks

Comment: well I don't know. Which of your scripts is changing the slider?

Comment: it call rangeslider.min.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to manually trigger the script

From looking at the documentation ( http://rangeslider.js.org/), the way to trigger the script is

```
 $('input[type="range"]').rangeslider();
```

So what you probably need to do is trigger this in your component's `ngAfterViewInit` method (the one using rangeslider). This need to be in `ngAfterViewInit`  to make sure that the dom elements have been created.

```
//component.ts
ngAfterViewInit()
{
   $('input[type="range"]').rangeslider();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the Angular CLI?
Then you can put your custom js files into .angular-cli.json

```
"scripts": [
    "<path_to_script",
    "<path_to_second_script"
]
```

Then you don't have to reference them in the index.html.

Comment: What exactly does not work when you reference them this way?

Comment: if i refreshed the page, the scripts files works, but when i used the spa navigation, the scripts dosen't load !

Comment: OK. Why should they load again? When navigating in a single page nothing gets loaded again, but the data you are loading manually from a server. What should the scripts do when you navigate?

Comment: i edit my question with an exemple what should a script file do.

Comment: OK. This seems to happen when the script is fully loaded automatically. So within the script a function gets called, when the script is loaded. But this is not possible when SPA navigation is used. Then you have to trigger script contents yourself.